# Django CMS Landing Page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-cms

How can I configure the page tree so that the landing page is not included in the standard navbar on the "home" page.

Are there any best practice I should be aware of? For instance would modifying my base `urls.py` and/or base `menu.html` template to achieve this routing have any ramifications down the line?

[image: DjangoCMS page tree is as followed.]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I made some updates and will refer back to it moving forward!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to exclude a page from the menus is found in that page tree screenshot. Take note of the 'Menu' column and if you don't want something to appear in the menu, de-select that option & publish the page.

The other way to do it is to change what levels of the page tree get put into the menu. The docs would be well worth a read at this point;
http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/navigation.html

The way I usually do it is to have your home page the only page at that root level, then nest your next level of pages within the home page. With that approach, you can ignore the root (home) page using this tag;

```
{% show_menu 1 100 100 100 "menu.html" %}
```

If I recall, that starts the menu at level 1, then shows the complete tree as a nested list.